# Set UITabBarController as rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITabBarController` and I want to show this screen and not the login screen if the user session is still active.

My `UITabBarController` has 3 `ViewControllers` and the problem is that I don't see the `TabBar` links in the bottom and I'm unable to navigate.

[image]

Without the following code everything works fine. I mean after login I can navigate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            window?.rootViewController = HomeTabBarController()
        }

        return true
    }
```

I have also tried the following code to set the `rootViewController` but it's the same problem.

When I try to set one of the other view controllers as root (one of the children), the Tab Bar doesn't show at all

```
var rootView: MyRootViewController = MyRootViewController()

if let window = self.window{
    window.rootViewController = rootView
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: "My UITabBarController has 3 ViewControllers" Really? I don't see you giving HomeTabBarController _any_ child view controllers. Show the code where that happens. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I have in my storyboard three relationship segues to the TabBarController. Please check my new screenshot in the updated question.

Comment: Okay but you are saying `window?.rootViewController = HomeTabBarController()`. That is not the one in the storyboard.

Comment: If I set it like this `window?.rootViewController = HomeTabBarController` I get this error: `Cannot assign value of type 'HomeTabBarController.Type' to type 'UIViewController?'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution: As @matt suggested I had to fetch the HomeTabBarController that’s in the storyboard.

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)


   let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

   // controller identifier sets up in storyboard utilities
   // panel (on the right), it called Storyboard ID
   let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabBarController") as! HomeTabBarController

   self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
   self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

   window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   window?.rootViewController = viewController
```

Comment: You could also just set the HomeTabBarController to be the initial view controller in the story board, and all the above code would be unnecessary.

Comment: How can I do that? I mean I still need to show the login form if the user session has clicked log out

Comment: Read up about adding child view controllers (it's a thing, but commonly forgotten by many iOS devs), or just general navigation flow. It's all about how you structure your project, and making a custom window and setting the root VC manually is just going to cause you headaches later on.

Comment: Do you mean `performSegue()` by 'adding child view controllers'. Because right now what I have found is one using `rootViewController` and the other is `performSegue()`. Could you give me some more information please on which is the best way to show or to hide the login screen depending if the session is active or not.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same issue and I came across your post, the problem with your code is that `HomeTabBarController()` is creating a whole new TabBarController so to fix it try the following approach I used.

```swift
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

            print("******************************User Present******************************")
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            // create view controllers from storyboard
            // Interface Builder -> Identitiy Inspector -> Storyboard ID
            // Set up the Tab Bar Controller to have two tabs
            let tabBarController  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTabBarController") as! HomeTabBarController
            // Make the Tab Bar Controller the root view controller
            window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

**Edit** Make sure to add the Identifier to your TabBarController

> ```
>     // Interface Builder -> Identitiy Inspector -> Storyboard ID
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //// this code changes the initial point of aap///////

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let nav = UINavigationController()
        let myview = SettingTabbar()
        nav.viewControllers = [myview]
        window?.rootViewController = nav
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
And Function SettingTabbar is:
func SettingTabbar()->(UITabBarController)
{
    //Setting TabBar
    let tabbar = UITabBarController()

    //Designing Tabbar Item Images
    let table = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image:UIImage(named: "002-list") , tag: 0)
    let collection = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "001-collect"), tag: 1)
    let insert = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "add"), tag: 2)

    //Getting TabBar ViewControllers
    let TableView = newViewController()
    let CollectionView = PersonCollectionViewController()
    let InsertRec = nextViewController()
    //Setting ViewControllers on TabBar Items
    TableView.tabBarItem = table
    CollectionView.tabBarItem = collection
    InsertRec.tabBarItem = insert
    let controllers = [TableView,CollectionView,InsertRec]
    tabbar.viewControllers = controllers
    tabbar.viewControllers = controllers.map{UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)}
    //Setting Title
    tabbar.navigationItem.title = "Person Record"

    return tabbar

}
```

Comment: This method is without storyboard

Comment: if you want that method then delete storyboard also from info.plist

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
window?.rootViewController = HomeTabBarController()
```

That is the wrong HomeTabBarController. It is a totally new HomeTabBarController with no children. You need to fetch the HomeTabBarController that’s in the storyboard.

Comment: But how can I do that. If I set it like this `window?.rootViewController = HomeTabBarController` I get this error: `Cannot assign value of type 'HomeTabBarController.Type' to type 'UIViewController?'`